# How do I know if I need to go back 1 or 2 levels when using Angular Router 3

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

I had the following code `<a routerLink="./edit/{{thing.name}}">{{thing.name}}</a>`. Then on the edit router I have the following...

`constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute
) {
        // If we have a param the close link goes back 2 level, otherwise it is 1
        this.route.params
            .map(params => params['name'])
            .subscribe((id) => {
                if(id){
                    this.closeLink += "../"
                }
            });
        ...
}`

I noticed that I could change the original HTML to `<a [routerLink]="['edit', {name: thing.name}]">{{thing.name}}</a>`. However, now the url changes to `../thing/edit;name=asdsadsa` instead of `/edit/asdsadsa`. Both of these urls work but the later needs to go back 2 levels where the former needs to go back 1. Is there a router service or something I can use to tell how many levels I need to go back. This is bound to get dynamic and I am not sure I will always know `thing`.